# center input in bootstrap with input-prepend

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="offset4 span4">
                <h1 class="text-center">Days</h1>
                <form method="post" action="proc/days.php" id="jobs">
                    <div class="input-prepend">
                        <span class="add-on">Job Count</span>
                        <input type="text" class="day1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-prepend">
                        <span class="add-on">Day Name</span>
                        <input type="text" class="day2">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

is my primary block of code (with all the other stuff striped out). I want to get the input-prepend to take up all the width available in the span4.

Right now, the only tricks I can find end up not working, or being way to large.

Also, I am using the Cosmo Bootswatch theme.

Comment: If you have left/right padding applied to `input-prepend`, keep in mind that setting the width to `100%` will make it extend beyond the parent container (because padding adds to width).  Other than that, you should post a working example of your code.  It's nearly impossible to see what's going on without both HTML and CSS being present.

Comment: @Axel [here](http://vps.syfaro.net/DutyRoster/days.php) is a live version of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `.day`1 to 76% width (after padding and borders are considered etc) will fill up your space. Problem would then be that you have another element depending on the `.day1` class. So add an id, or example like:

```
<input type="text" class="day1" id="day1">
```

and then use `#day1 {width:76%;}` in your css. You'd most likely need to adjust the width size as your screen width changes though (through media queries).

Comment: this works well. any chance you know of the required css for the media queries? I'm not exactly sure as to how you could do that.

Comment: Great! Here's the bootstrap explanation for media querires: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive which should give a good start.